# How to get link from javascript.void(0) using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a new scraper and I am trying to scrape category and products links from this website but I can see that, they use

> href="javascript.void(0)"

on href attribute section. So How can i get the URL?
Here is the website URL https://www.harristeeter.com/shop/store/168

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked Link Extractors yet? If not, please visit here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No, I didn't check yet.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html